# Create % overlap matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, overlap

I want to take a set of observations & find out how much overlap different columns have based on the indicators. I have the following data:

```
uniquevalue |  X   |   Y   |    Z   |
Obs 1       |  1   |   0   |    1   |
Obs 2       |  1   |   1   |    0   |
Obs 3       |  1   |   0   |    1   |
Obs 4       |  0   |   1   |    0   |
Obs 5       |  0   |   0   |    1   |
Obs 6       |  0   |   1   |    0   |
Obs 7       |  0   |   0   |    1   |
```

I want to create the following data overlap matrix:

```
Label  |   X  |   Y  |   Z  |
X      | 100% |  33% |  50% |
Y      |  33% | 100% |   0% |
Z      |  66% |   0% | 100% |
```

So, for example, Z has a total of 4 observations. 2 of its 4 observations are also present on X, so its overlap % is 50%. However because different columns have different numbers of observations, the reverse is not necessarily true. As you can see, 2 of 3 observations in X are shared with Z, so its a 66% overlap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `crossprod`:

```
mat <- crossprod(as.matrix(df[2:4]))            # calculate the overlap               
floor(t(mat * 100 / diag(mat)))                 # calculate the percentage

#    X   Y   Z
#X 100  33  50
#Y  33 100   0
#Z  66   0 100
```